Why tension in a spring is equal to spring force
If a spring is connected to a string then how tension and spring force are equal


Consider a point P at the junction between the spring and string .The point mass P has negligible mass and if the net force acting on it is non zero , the acceleration of point P will tend to infinity which isn't practically possible and hence the net force on P is zero.
Since the point P has a very small mass , we can safely neglect the weight force. Excluding the weight ,the only two forces acting on point mass P is Tension Force of string and Spring Force which are,by their nature,in opposite directions. Since the net force is zero ,the magnitudes of Spring Force and Tension Force are equal.
Alternatively,You can use the direct result : The Net Force on a massless body is always zero which is a very helpful tool in Newtonian Mechanics

The tension force equals the spring force in the case where the string and spring are connected and massless. Consider a small sliver of the string/spring located at the intersection of the string and spring. The forces acting on this sliver are tension $T$ and the spring force $F_s$, and have opposite directions. The sliver also has zero mass. Newton's 2nd Law then gives $T-F_s=F_{\text{net}}=m_{\text{sliver}}a=0\cdot a=0$. So $T=F_s$. ($T$ and $F_s$ are also constant throughout the string and spring (resp.) because of a similar argument using mass.)
Otherwise, if the string and spring are not connected but are two separate objects, there is no reason to expect that $T=F_s$. If $m$ is the mass of the object and $a$ is its acceleration, N2L yields only $T+F_s-mg=ma$.
